# I want to remove these null values from output in mysql i have event column which i divided into 3,4,5,6 column

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT t1.client_name,FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")AS Date, 
case whent1.event='ALL_OFF'then
    (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),
         FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)))) end as ALL_OFF,
case when t1.event = 'HOME_ON' then 
   (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp))))  end as HOME_ON,
case when t1.event = 'OFFICE_ON' then 
   (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)))) end as OFFICE_ON,
case when t1.event = 'PARTY_ON' then 
   (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp))))  end as PARTY_ON,
case when t1.event = 'OUTDOOR_ON' then 
   (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp))))  end as OUTDOOR_ON
FROM logs13 AS t1 
JOIN logs13 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id - 1) 
       where  t1.wonderFit_ID = '0000000037fd0ef6' and t1.client_name ='Puma'  And FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%Y")='2017' and FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%M")='April'  and Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) >= 0 
group by t1.event, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")  
order by FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d");
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What value are you expecting in the place of NULL ?

If you need something like 0 in the place of NULL, you can use the following format

```
CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN value1 ELSE value2 END
```

Example:

```
CASE when t1.event='ALL_OFF' THEN (SUM(Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp), FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)))) ELSE 0 END as ALL_OFF
```

Comment: i dont want 0 as well because when i using trend line in my dashboard not looks good..so i want values only

Comment: Can you give your expected output ? It will be helpful

Comment: **i don't want 0** but these are numeric columns you would have to convert all the numbers into strings to output '' instead of NULL.  It's zero or NULL if you want to keep those columns as numeric.

Comment: But if i am converted into strings line chart will not be  displayed ..and i want a seperated line for  all  events (alloff,homeon,officeon,partyon,outdooron)

Answer (score 0):

Place whole case expressions inside the SUM(case when ... else ... end) function then use COALESCE(SUM( ... ),0)

```
SELECT
        t1.client_name
      , FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d") AS Date
      , COALESCE(SUM(case when t1.event = 'ALL_OFF'    then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end),0) as ALL_OFF
      , COALESCE(SUM(case when t1.event = 'HOME_ON'    then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end),0) as HOME_ON
      , COALESCE(SUM(case when t1.event = 'OFFICE_ON'  then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end),0) as OFFICE_ON
      , COALESCE(SUM(case when t1.event = 'PARTY_ON'   then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end),0) as PARTY_ON
      , COALESCE(SUM(case when t1.event = 'OUTDOOR_ON' then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end),0) as OUTDOOR_ON
FROM logs13 AS t1 
JOIN logs13 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id - 1) 
WHERE  t1.wonderFit_ID = '0000000037fd0ef6' 
AND t1.client_name ='Puma'  
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%Y")='2017' 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%M")='April'  
AND Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) >= 0 
GROUP BY t1.event, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")  
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")
;
```

In MYSQL you could use IFNULL() instead of COALESCE() but the late is part of the SQL standard and I find it better to avoid dbms specific functions where possible.

---

**OR to oputput '' instead of zero**

```
SELECT
        t1.client_name
      , FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d") AS Date
      , COALESCE(CAST(SUM(case when t1.event = 'ALL_OFF'    then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end) AS CHAR),'') as ALL_OFF
      , COALESCE(CAST(SUM(case when t1.event = 'HOME_ON'    then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end) AS CHAR),'') as HOME_ON
      , COALESCE(CAST(SUM(case when t1.event = 'OFFICE_ON'  then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end) AS CHAR),'') as OFFICE_ON
      , COALESCE(CAST(SUM(case when t1.event = 'PARTY_ON'   then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end) AS CHAR),'') as PARTY_ON
      , COALESCE(CAST(SUM(case when t1.event = 'OUTDOOR_ON' then Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp),FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) end) AS CHAR),'') as OUTDOOR_ON
FROM logs13 AS t1 
JOIN logs13 AS t2 ON (t2.id = t1.id - 1) 
WHERE  t1.wonderFit_ID = '0000000037fd0ef6' 
AND t1.client_name ='Puma'  
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%Y")='2017' 
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%M")='April'  
AND Timestampdiff(MINUTE,FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.timestamp) , FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp)) >= 0 
GROUP BY t1.event, FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")  
ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.timestamp,"%d")
;
```

Comment: *showing varchar is unexpected* ... is there more information? an error message? what have you tried to do to fix it? please note I cannot run your query

Comment: My mistake use **CHAR** not VARCHAR

Comment: it converted into string i dont want to convert into string

Comment: sigh. You have a choice from limited options. **1. keep the column numeric and accept NULL;** `2. keep the columns numeric and output 0 instead of null;` *3. to give the impression of blankness in a cell output a "blank string" which also has the requirement to convert the whole column into strings.* Don't shoot the messenger bt the column CANNOT output blank strings if you want the column as numeric.

Comment: ohh understand so what i want that is not possible ..anyways thanks alot

Comment: well the combination you want isn't possible now yo have made the choice, but the answers are still technically correct.

Comment: do you know how to capture the  time from timestamp when screen getting on?